# How get a list of events near a certain venue/location?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation, facebook-fql

I need a list of events near a certain location. As far as I can see it is not possible to do geolocation based searches with the Graph API. Can this be achieved with the FQL? Does anybody have experience with such a problem? I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do geolocation based searches for places:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=44.4325,26.1039&distance=100